# Calling bit.ly REST API from Apex

Tags: apex, callout

Using Bit.ly V4 API via this code:

```
HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();           
req2.setEndpoint('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten');           
req2.setMethod('POST');
req2.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ...');
String jsonBody = '{"long_url":"https://test.com"}';
req2.setBody(jsonBody);
req2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Http http2 = new Http();
HttpResponse res2 = http2.send(req2);           
system.debug(res2);
```

yields the following response:

```
CALLOUT_RESPONSE [24] | System.HttpResponse [Status = Not Acceptable, StatusCode = 406]
```

The same request works in Postman. Why doesn't it work in Apex?

Comment: Instead of setting the auth header in the code, have you tried using named credentials?

Comment: can you try with application as a small in your content type. Not sure, but if they're handling case-sensitive it could be an issue.

Comment: @YsrShk yes, tried change. not case-sensitive

Comment: @arut it's just a little piece of code to test. We have class with  named credentials and 2 methods

Comment: @YevhenB It's kind of difficult to track down this issue (since the final headers sent by HttpRequest & Http classes are not known exactly) and also, no clue of how Bitly is processing the request sent. From a quick test that I did, I got the same response even after commenting out the line of code for authorization header. This basically tells me that Bitly might not have even tried to authorize the request due to some missing header information.  So, it would be easier to let named credential handle the auth even for testing (unless you are really want to troubleshoot this).

Comment: @arut  the "Authorization" parameter is used as the header. it requires the Bitley. I am not sure, this parameter can use in named credential.

Comment: @YevhenB If you use named credential, you wouldn't have to explicitly supply this authorization header. As a part of named credential creation, you will have to create an auth provider and the config specified in this provider will be used to generate auth token by the named credential. So, the entire auth responsibility can be handed over to named credential and you can simply make the http call to the endpoint with request body. Besides, this would be the recommended approach for prod  env.

Comment: @arut Good. 1 request: `callout:bitlyv4/oauth/access_token` - I use the NC in which I register the user and password to receive a token. 2 request: `callout:bitlyv4/v4/shorten` - I use the same NC (other endpoint) without the authorization header. I get the token on the first request, and on the second request again err406 (

Comment: So, in the NC, you have specified `Identity Type` as user, `Authentication Protocol` as Password Authentication & also, the credentials. Is that correct understanding? Did you enable `Generate Authorization Header` & `Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header`? [enabling the second one may not be required]. Also, have you checked this link (https://dev.bitly.com/docs/getting-started/authentication) for anything specifically required by Bitly?

Comment: Yes, I used 'Password Authentication' & 'Generate Authorization Header' in NC. I checked Bitly docs for authentication. I've got wright 1 response, but second...   It all works in Postmen but doesn't work in SF APEX :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code snippet

```
Http http2 = new Http();
HttpResponse res2 = http2.send(req2);           
system.debug(res2);
```

sends the reference (`res2`) to debug log. When this happens, SF calls `toString()` method on the reference and you see `System.HttpResponse [Status = Not Acceptable, StatusCode = 406]` as the result. `toString` gives you the class name and status string + associated code. That is not enough information to see what's going on.

If you send the *body* of the response to debug log in addition to status like so

```
system.debug(res2.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res2.getBody());
```

you'd see

```
<timestamp> USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|406: {"message":"INVALID_ACCEPT_HEADER"}
```

This pretty much tells you what's wrong - you need to include the `Accept` header to indicate that your client can accept JSON as the response. This works:

```
...
req2.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

Http http2 = new Http();
HttpResponse res2 = http2.send(req2);           
system.debug(res2.getStatusCode() + ': ' + res2.getBody());
```

Depending on configuration, Postman may automatically add headers to the request. While it seemed like your request in Postman was the same as it was in Apex, it really wasn't. When testing REST APIs, it's better to use a command-line client such as `curl`.

Comment: Thank you! You are the best! :)